# N Nested squares

Tags: haskell

The excercise is to print n nested squares. The nested squares are given as input by the user.

Example output for n = 4:

```
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│   ┌────────────────────────┐   │
│   │   ┌────────────────┐   │   │
│   │   │   ┌────────┐   │   │   │
│   │   │   │        │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │        │   │   │   │
│   │   │   └────────┘   │   │   │
│   │   └────────────────┘   │   │
│   └────────────────────────┘   │
└────────────────────────────────┘
```

My solution:

```
import Data.List

line :: Int -> String -> String -> String -> String
line n start middle end = start ++ m ++ end
  where m = foldl1 (++) (replicate n middle)

topLine :: Int -> String
topLine n = line n "┌" "────" "┐"

middleLine :: Int -> String
middleLine n = line n "│" "    " "│"

bottomLine :: Int -> String
bottomLine n = line n "└" "────" "┘"

square :: Int -> [String]
square n = topLine n : middle ++ [bottomLine n]
  where middle = take n (repeat (middleLine n))

concentricSquares :: Int -> String
concentricSquares n = intercalate "\n" merged
  where size = n * 2
        squares = map square [2, 4 .. size]
        merged = foldl1 mergeSquares squares

mergeSquares :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
mergeSquares x (y:ys) = y : zipWith mergeLines x ys ++ [last ys]

mergeLines :: String -> String -> String
mergeLines x y = [head y] ++ "   " ++ x ++ "   " ++ [last y]

main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn "Enter square number:" >>
  getLine >>= \num -> putStrLn (concentricSquares (read num))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks fine. Every top-level binding has a type signature, and all functions are nice and short. However, the `mergeLines` and `mergeSquares` functions could use a little bit more documentation. There is also (probably) an algorithm that doesn't introduce that many lines just to throw them away in `mergeLines`.

Other than that, there are three possible improvements:

- `foldl1 (++)` is `concat`.
- `take n . repeat` is `replicate n` (in `square`)
- `getLine >>= \num -> f (g (read num))` is `readLn >>= \num -> f (g num)`

  We can therefore write `readLn >>= putStrLn . concentricSquares` in `main`.